# Laravel prevent translation of route resource parameter name

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization, laravel-artisan

When using a trans() function on a route resource in my web.php:

```
Route::resource(trans('routes.users'), DashboardUserController::class, ['as' => 'dashboard', 'names' => 'users']);
```

And in routes.php:

```
return [
    'users' => 'gebruikers'
];
```

art route:list gives me this output:
[image]

Notice that the route parameter is also translated. But that's not what I want. I want `{user}` instead of the Dutch translation `{gebruiker}`.

How to do so with a route resource?

I could write out the entire resource like I did with my advetisement resource:

```
Route::get(trans('routes.advertisements') . '/{advertisement}/' . trans('edit'), [DashboardAdvertisementController::class, 'edit'])->name('dashboard.advertisements.edit');
```

And then the translation is correct. The path is dutch but the parameter stays in English.
`dashboard/advertenties/{advertisement}/bewerk`

But I would also like to be able to do so with resources. Making the web.php file a lot shorter. And let's face it, it's too much work writing out all the resource paths.

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your question, but is Dutch your only available language? This approach will only register the routes in whatever Language Laravel was set to on start-up, but if you also wanted `dashboard/users/create`, this approach wouldn't work (I think, `trans()` uses `app()->getLocale()`, which _can_ be changed via `app()->setLocale()` at runtime, but I'm not sure if this would recreate the routes)

Comment: So far I only use it for the Dutch language. But you are right. I just tested it with my switch-locale path and the vars change but not the paths. What a bummer. What would be correct way to translate routes?

Comment: In my experience, you don't  If your application handles all the routing, there should be no need for it to be in multiple languages, as the end-user likely isn't going to interact with it directly (aside from copy/paste for bug reports, or similar). If you _need_ to register the same Route in multiple languages, you can, but you'd have to loop over each of your languages and construct the `Route::{whatever}(...)` entries based on the iterated locale. Something like `foreach($languages as $locale) { app()->setLocale($locale); /* Then define your Routes */ }`. Great question though! 

Comment: Okay. So all routes have to be defined in web.php in all available languages in order for it to work?

Comment: That's correct 

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (And I am using Lang::uri instead of trans() now so it also works when switching locales at runtime.)

```
Route::resource(Lang::uri('users'), DashboardUserController::class, 
['as' => 'dashboard', 'names' => 'users'])
// add this:
->parameters([Lang::uri('advertisements') => 'advertisement']);
```

By adding the parameters method I translate the parameter itself back to English.

Kinda hacky. But it works!